# Keyboard shortcut Command + backtick (`) disabled, re-enable?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have accidentally assigned the shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to something undesired, while the shortcut in default was been used to switch between opening windows inside the same currently active app.

How can I get it back to the default state?
Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open System Preferences > Keyboard, open the Shortcuts tab and select Keyboard (you should see the option "Move focus to next window").

To re-enable it, either:

- click the "Restore Defaults" button,
- or double click the shortcut and set it back to <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>
  [image: Keyboard settings]

Comment: Hi @Ambidextrous, I've expanded your answer with information on how to open to the "Keyboard" window and what to do when you get there. I hope it's OK :-)